# How to solve Hoffman & Kunze exercise 4, section 10.2

Tags: linear-algebra

> Describe explicitly all bilinear forms $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the property that $f(\alpha,\beta)=f(\beta,\alpha)$ for all $\alpha,\beta$

Can someone explain this to me? I don't know what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

A bilinear form is determined by the values on a basis.  Take the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, e.g., then we must have 
$$f_{ij}=f(e_i,e_j)=f(e_j,e_i).$$
Now the matrix $F$ with that entries represents the bilinear for $f$ in the sense that 
$$f(v,w)=v^tFw.$$  It's a symmetric one, for sure.

Comment: So, the idea of the exercise is to interpretate that F must be symmetric, and describe what a symmetric 3x3 matrix is?

Comment: That's what I presume.